Data is not coming at server end
I have created a registration form. So when user filled that data, expected behaviour is, at server business logic should be applied on that data.
Through req field data should come at server. But it is not coming. req.body is empty
Here is my code
Register.jsx
 function Register() {
  const [registerUser, setRegisterUser] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      const response = await RegisterUser(registerUser);
      // some code 
  };
}       
 

users.js
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:5000";

export const RegisterUser = async (registerUser) => {
  console.log("In RegisterUser =====> ", registerUser);  // getting data properly
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/api/users/register", registerUser);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response.data;
  }
};

server.js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();
const dbConfig = require("./Config/dbConfig");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = require("http").createServer(app);

const usersRoute = require("./routes/usersRoutes");

app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));

app.use("/api/users", usersRoute);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));      
  

usersRoutes.js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/userModel");

// User Registration
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {

    if (!req.body)    
       console.log("EMPTY");    // EMPTY is getting printed

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: "User already exists",
      });
    }
    const newUser = new User(req.body);
    await newUser.save();
    res.send({
      success: true,
      message: "User created successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({
      message: error.message,
      success: false,
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;     
 

In above code, I am getting error as :

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')

In RegisterUser(), I  tried to printed data through

console.log("In RegisterUser =====> ", registerUser);

and it is coming properly.
But when I try to print data at server side using

if (!req.body)
console.log("EMPTY");

it is coming EMPTY.
Why data is not coming at server side ?

You didn't setup body parser

try app.use(express.json()); and app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

as i understand you didn't get data in req.body correct?if not please elobrate it.
as per your code you have'nt add body-parser. due to that you not able to get the response follow the below steps.


//in Terminal 

npm i body-parser

  // in server.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())



